# Objective C - UserDefaults Over Writing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I can't seem to re edit this object in my ios User Defaults. Here is my code...

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:nil forKey:@"savedScoreCards2"];
```

Before I did this I set the key savedScoreCards to a huge 3-d dictionary, and now when I try to over write it or even set the key to nil that huge 3-d dictionary that I set up a while ago is still there. I can't seem to over write/ replace it will nothing (nil), or another huge 3-d dictionary. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

```
  + (void)saveCurrentScoreCard 
  {
    //save score card
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableDictionary *savedScoreCards = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [userDefaults setObject:nil forKey:@"savedScoreCards2"];//reset at beginning

    NSMutableArray *golferOneScoresu = [userDefaults arrayForKey:@"golferOneScoresArray"];
    NSMutableArray *golferTwoScoresu = [userDefaults arrayForKey:@"golferTwoScoresArray"];
    NSMutableDictionary *golferIconsu = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"golferIconsFirstScene"];
    NSMutableArray *golferThreeScoresu = [userDefaults arrayForKey:@"golferThreeScoresArray"];
    NSMutableArray *golferFourScoresu = [userDefaults arrayForKey:@"golferFourScoresArray"];
    NSMutableDictionary *golferIcons2u = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"golferIcons"];
    NSMutableArray *golferNamesu = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"golferNames"];

    NSMutableArray *golferNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:golferNamesu copyItems:YES];
    NSMutableDictionary *golferIconsSceneOne = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:golferIconsu];
    NSMutableDictionary *golferIcons = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:golferIcons2u];
    NSMutableArray *golferFourScores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:golferFourScoresu copyItems:YES];
    NSMutableArray *golferThreeScores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:golferThreeScoresu copyItems:YES];
    NSMutableArray *golferOneScores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:golferOneScoresu copyItems:YES];
    NSMutableArray *golferTwoScores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:golferTwoScoresu copyItems:YES];

    NSMutableDictionary *currentScoreCard = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [currentScoreCard setObject:golferNames forKey:@"golferNames"];
    [currentScoreCard setObject:golferIconsSceneOne forKey:@"golferIconsFirstScene"];
    [currentScoreCard setObject:golferIcons forKey:@"golferIcons"];
    [currentScoreCard setObject:golferOneScores forKey:@"golferOneScoresArray"];
    [currentScoreCard setObject:golferTwoScores forKey:@"golferTwoScoresArray"];
    [currentScoreCard setObject:golferThreeScores forKey:@"golferThreeScoresArray"];
    [currentScoreCard setObject:golferFourScores forKey:@"golferFourScoresArray"];

    [savedScoreCards setObject:currentScoreCard forKey:@"1"];

    NSLog([golferIconsSceneOne objectForKey:@"30101"]);

    [userDefaults setObject:savedScoreCards forKey:@"savedScoreCards2"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"SAVED SCORE CARD");
}
```

Comment: aside: as a matter of programming "best practices", if you're using a string literal more than once you should put it in a variable as limited in scope as possible or optionally a #define statement so that any typos don't send you astray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[userDefaults removeObjectForKey:@"savedScoreCards2"]` if you're just trying to remove a stored value.
Also call `[userDefaults synchronize];` to "flush" your changes immediately. I think the `[userDefaults synchronize]` is probably what you're missing.

Comment: Perhaps you're missing something else. Or your simulator might be in an unstable state. Reset it and try again...

Comment: I am changing the user defaults in a seperate class from where I'm opening them...

Comment: I just updated my question with the entire method that is supposed to save my data...

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults do not save automatically when you make a change to them.  Try adding this line below the ones you've posted above:

```
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

This should save any changes you've made.

As a side note, I'm not sure you can save 'nil' into NSUserDefaults; at its core I believe it's a dictionary, in which nil values cannot be set.  So you might try setting an empty object, instead.

Hope this helps, let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: What kind of object is stored in @"savedScoreCards2", exactly?  Is it a custom data type?  When you try to overwrite it, are you verifying that the object you are setting is valid (ie. not nil)?

Comment: It's a huge 3-d NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: What objects are contained at the lowest levels of the dictionary?  Objects that don't conform to NSCoding can't be stored in NSUserDefaults.  Failing that, I'd just delete the app off your device and try again; see if that fixes anything.

Comment: I just updated my question with the entire method that is supposed to save my data...

Comment: they're more restricted than NSCoding - you can only place "plist" values in the user defaults: _"A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary."_ [NSUserDefaults Class Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Just to clarify this answer, NSUserDefaults does save *automatically*, however it does not save *immediately*. The synchronize method is automatically called at periodic intervals.